# update qty per store view with csv file

Tags: magento-1.9, import, csv, importexport, qty-increment

actually in our website we have a cron function scheduled (every morning) to update the qty of all products of our catalog and works good.

Following the code we are using now:

---

```
<?php

define('MAGE_BASE_DIR', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once(MAGE_BASE_DIR . '/app/Mage.php');

$file = MAGE_BASE_DIR . "/var/import/inventory.csv";
$handle = @fopen($file, "r");
if ($handle) {
    require_once(MAGE_BASE_DIR . '/app/Mage.php');
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $linea = fgets($handle);
        $dati = explode(";", $linea);

        $aa = trim($dati[0]);
        $bb = trim($dati[0]);
        $cc = trim($dati[1]);
        $sku = trim($dati[2]);
        $dd = trim($dati[3]);
        $ee = trim($dati[4]);
        $qta = trim($dati[5]);
        $ff = trim($dati[7]);
        $gg = trim($dati[8]);
        $hh = trim($dati[8]);

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');

        $productId = $product->getIdBySku($sku);
        if ($productId !== false) {
            $product->load($productId);

            $stockItem->loadByProduct($productId);
            $stockItem->setData('qty', $qta);
            $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', ($qta > 0) ? 1 : 0);

            try {
                $stockItem->save();
                //echo "{$sku} elaborato correttamente.";
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $countException++;
                echo "{$sku} errore ({$e->getMessage()}).";
            }
        } else {
            //echo "{$sku} non trovato.";
        }

        unset($product);
        unset($stockItem);
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo "Errore apertura file. ({$file})";
    exit();
}
```

---

This code works to update all the website, what I'm asking you now is: how can I modify this file to update a specific store?

Comment: and if I create a different catalog? is possible? same website but a copy of the catalog..